# How to add dynamic roles managment to JHipster uaa project?

Tags: jhipster

I've generated a jhipster 4 project with uaa, a microservice and a gateway. I'd like to add new roles and assign them to users without manually modify the source code. I've explore deepu105's code but it not seems completed. Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

currently, the authorities in JHipster come from the source code.
If you need to make authorities stored in your database. In detail, these are the steps:

- add a new entity `Authority` (you can use `jhipster entity` for that)
- if not already done by the generator, add a `AuthorityResource` `@RestController`, exposing that entity via a REST API
- you can either enforce a user authority being set via `UserResource` to exist, or create it on-demand
- add the default roles (like `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`) in a CSV file, and load it using `loadData` in a Liquibase migration, like it is done with users
- for a better UX, you can even add `PUT/DELETE /api/user/{login}/authorities/{authorityName}` to your `UserResource`